# Install motog stock framework

Tags: rom, motorola-moto-g

I installed cynogen mod 12 to my motoG, now I want to install stock rom, I got it from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/development/rom-stock-motorola-lollipop-rom-t3017510), But how can I install? can anyone please give me steps to install it?

Answer (score 0):

The XDA post you referenced tells you how to do what you are asking (taken from the XDA post):

How to flash:

1. Download ROM to Internal SD.
2. Boot into Custom Recovery.
3. Factory Reset (System, Data, Cache, Dalvik)*
4. Flash ROM with TWRP and reboot.

*NB: It is often also necessary to Wipe > Format /data > Yes (Warning: This will erase internal storage) - Do this before reporting any bugs.

Comment: ,I am expecting the detailed procedure, not copy from given link